# Ubuntu Emulator installation from Ubuntu SDK in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to Install Ubuntu Emulator in Ubuntu 12.04

These are things I have done to install

- Started Ubuntu SDK
- Clicked Devices
- Selected Emulators
- Clicked install

But I am not able to install it properly. I checked the log I got the following errors

```
Checking installed emulator package.
The package is not installed.
Detecting device..
* there is no device connected.
Install the emulator package on the system..
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

E: Unable to locate package android-emulator
```

But I have installed Eclipse and the Android emulator runs properly there without fail.

Comment: did you follow instuction here >> http://davidplanella.org/ubuntu-emulator-quickstart-guide/ For me, it is easier to get it works with 14.04 Trusty, event still in development mode.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04..  I went to this link for downloading [Android packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/android) but it is for The Saucy Salamander Version 13.10. Can I download and use for me ?

Comment: When I try to create the instance I am getting this error..

Get https://system-image.ubuntu.com/channels.json: dial tcp: lookup system-image.ubuntu.com: no such host

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
```